# Recycle view in Android java

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

Recycler View is not iterating to the length of array.
Here is the code, what am i missing. i followed a guide describing the entire process, in that guide all items of the array is visible in the list view.
Here is the main activity file that host the recyclerView, below the adapter java class that filter through the array and pop out the list View. please help me

PickupActivity.java

```
package com.demo.driverconsole;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerViewAccessibilityDelegate;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Adapter;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class pickupActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG = "pickupActivity";
    private RecyclerView studentList;
    private  RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    private ArrayList<String> myDataset = new ArrayList<>();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_pickup);
        myDataset.add("John Doe");
        myDataset.add("Jane Doe");
        myDataset.add("Susan");
        initRecycler();

    }

    public void initRecycler() {
        Log.d(TAG, "Called");
        RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        StudentListAdapter adapter = new StudentListAdapter(myDataset);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    }
}
```

StudentListAdapter.java

```
package com.datastoneglobal.driverconsole;

import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class StudentListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<StudentListAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private static final String TAG = "StudentListAdapter";
    private ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<>();

    public StudentListAdapter(ArrayList<String> names) {
        Log.d(TAG, "StudentListAdapter: " + names);
        this.names = names;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.student_item, parent, false);
        ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(view);
        return vh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.text.setText(names.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return names.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView text;
        RelativeLayout layout;
        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            text = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        }
    }


}
```

ActivityPickup.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<RelativeLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"></android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

StudentItem.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="Loading ...">
    </TextView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: what is a problem? I can't understand your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code looks right the only problem i find is the hight of your `RelativeLayout` in  `StudentItem.xml`

Change the hight of your `RelativeLayout` to **`android:layout_height="wrap_content"`** in your `StudentItem.xml`

**SAMPLE CODE**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="Loading ...">
    </TextView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**EDIT**

Use this

```
private  StudentListAdapter adapter;
```

Instead of this

```
private  RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
```

Answer (score 1):

⬇ Remove this code ⬇

```
public class StudentListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<StudentListAdapter.ViewHolder>
{
    // ....
}
```

⬇ use this code ⬇

```
public class StudentListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>
    {
        // ....
    }
```

because you extend :- 
public class StudentListAdapter

`extends RecyclerView.Adapter<StudentListAdapter.ViewHolder>`

and you extend at here :- public class ViewHolder `extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder`